# Co-Authoring in Office Web Apps 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, co-authoring

I am using SharePoint Server 2013 And I am opening the documents from the library using Office Web Apps. Everything is working Fine, but when two users started working on the same file (Excel, PPT, Word...) they cannot see whom is working on that file. The Co-authoring Feature is not working!

Is there anything to configure in SharePoint or in the Office Web Apps Server?

Comment: See the answer by Chris O'Brian here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/word-2010-co-authoring-what-is-required-to-get-it-working. 
'require checkout' needs to NOT be set on document libraries you want to use for co-authoring....Changes are brought into the document as you save in Word....OneNote is different as it saves continuously without user action, and it's recommended to turn minor versioning off in doc libs. ALSO you wont see each other typing in real time(like google docs), Microsoft uses paragraph locking so you see the changes when you save the save the file